# R Studio 'source' button fails with escape error

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a fresh install of R Studio.  Editing a file and clicking the 'source' button produces the error below.

How do I fix the default behavior of R Studio to properly escape the path?

The output in the R console is:

> source('~/pull tfs data.r')

```
Error: '\L' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""Z:\L"
```

Comment: What is the line of the file that produces the error?

Comment: I'm guessing you're on a Windows machine? When you specify fie paths in R, you should either use "/" or use "\\" to properly avoid os escape the directory delimiter.

Comment: I thought rstudio was failing to source the file, I was wrong.  The error was actually being produced by a line in the file that was improperly escaped.  My bad.  Thanks.  This is a bad question and might want to be closed.